# Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class className {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.geckodriver" , "F:\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("<URL>");
        driver.findElement(By.id("<first field>")).click();

          //This line through the error
        WebElement a= driver.findElement(By.id("<id>")).sendKeys("<abc>");

        driver.findElement(By.id("<second field>")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("<field name")).sendKeys("<xyz>");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

in this program, the following line throws an error as *Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement*.

New to automation. Help is greatly needed

Answer (score 2):

This error is thrown because of the in the following line

```
WebElement a= driver.findElement(By.id("<id>")).sendKeys("<abc>");
```

You are declaring a variable of type `WebElement` here, but calling `sendKeys()` method which `returns void`. Remove the `sendKeys()` method call from the line.

Write the code like -

```
WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.id("<id>"));
a.sendKeys();
```

Comment: I have one problem. The data is not getting entered in the username field. The login page opens correctly. But the username and password whatever i passed is not getting entered in it. I used the same program above. Please help

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?? I think it might be because the element is not yet visible and the script is trying to enter the text. Write the implicit wait statment at the top i.e. After defining driver = new ChromeDriver()

Comment: i'm not getting any error. The webpage in firefox is opening correctly. but the username and password is not getting entered in those fields. i used the same program mentioned above

Comment: This might be because your geckodriver might not be supporting the firefox version. Try updating the firefox version to latest and also the geckodriver.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has already been resolved but still the issue that you will be getting is due to the firefox driver.

Trying using gecko driver and set the properties as:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver" , "F:\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id(""));
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! Can you explain your answer with more than just code? Please review https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer